# How to handle huge traffic on WebSocket server in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I use `ws` library in Node.JS. <strike>When I've got more than 100 clients, the WebSocket server can't handle all traffic, the server lags, but if users are disconnected, the server works correctly. I use `Heroku` to host servers. What can I do for optimize my servers/app? Should I use another service than `Heroku`?</strike>

EDIT: I'm using paid version of Heroku (Hobby). My script isn't long (about 140 lines).

EDIT: I have 3 x VPS Cloud 3 from OVH.

- OpenStack KVM
- 99.99% SLA
- 4 vCores
- 3.1 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- 100 GB
- High Availability NVMe (Ceph)
- Bandwidth 100 Mbps
- Ubuntu Server 15
- 17 IPs per server

Client -> VPS 1 -> ((VPS 2 -> example.com) + (VPS 3 -> example.com)) -> VPS 1 -> Client

Comment: Are you using free instances of heroku or have you added 'paid for' resources to your instance? Assuming you have a user base that causes such a strong load on the server, they should be generating enough revenue to warrant adding resources.

Comment: Your question is super wide and hard to answer... we need more information about your application... Generally speaking, **Javascript is single threaded** - this means that if your code is long or blocking, your server won't be able to respond to many clients. To resolve this issue, **use more callbacks**, this allows the Javascript engine to switch between tasks more often and respond to waiting clients between callbacks. Your responses might take a moment longer, but you'll be optimizing your existing resources and you'll be able to answer more requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question does not contain enough information to properly answer the question. There are a lot of factors that can contribute to this. To name a few:

- Machine spec's (memory, cpu etc)
- IO (HDD speed)
- File Descriptors
- Code (multi-core, threads etc)
- Bandwidth
- Networking constraints

As someone else stated, Node.JS is typically running on a single core with asynchronous IO. Concurrency, as I've argued with many people in the past, is not parallelism. There is a huge difference. That doesn't mean Node couldn't be used to support more users, but it also depends on how you've implemented it and all of the other factors lying underneath. Think of a car that simply won't start. You can't just say, "Hey, my car won't start - why not?" At the same time, you can't simply say, "Hey, my car starts, but sometimes when driving, it vibrates badly and makes funny noises."

Can you put the Node.JS web socket code you're using up on a pastebin, and also include information on the server it's running on? Some good info from there would be:

cat /proc/meminfo
cat /proc/cpuinfo
ulimit -a

Also, the bandwidth you have (100mb? 10mb?)

Those would be good starting grounds to look at the problem and try and determine where the bottleneck is.

Oh, if you're on an OpenVZ host, it would be useful if you could give the bean counter information.

Comment: Hmm... Heroku doesn't give me infos about servers. What VPS do You prefer?

Comment: Personally, I use intovps and vpscheap.net for quick small servers. intovps is one of the better ones from both a price and technical support aspect. Those guys REALLY know their stuff. By default, they're a little strict on the bean counters... But they'll adjust as you need them to. They are OpenVZ containers.